# Vue api service showing error and not working at all

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am trying to call my vue api service via axios. However, it does not work at all and I am getting `Network Error` message on my browser console.
Could anyone advice what I did wrong? Below I have attached my code from by the client and server side.

**error**
[image]

**api.js**

```
const axios = require('axios')

export default () => {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:1991'
  })
}
```

**api_metrics.js**

```
import api from '@/services/api.js'
const url = api() + '/api/metrics/'

export default {
  getIpAddress () {
    console.log(url)
    return api().get(url)
  }
}
```

**express_server.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express()

// middleware
app.use(cors())

const metrics = require('./routes/api/metrics') 
app.use('/api/metrics', metrics)

const port = process.env.PORT || 1991

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`server running on port ${port}`)
})
```

**server_api.js**

```
const express = require('express')    
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    console.log('getIpAddress ')
    res.send('"metrics"')
})

module.exports = router
```

**home.vue**

```
        <template>
            <p>Home</p>
        </template>

        <script>
        export default {
          data: () => ({
             this.user_information = []
          }),
          async created () {
             try {
                   this.user_information = await 
                   apiService.getIpAddress()
                   console.log(this.user_information)
              } catch (err) {
                   console.log(err.message)
              }
          }
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Comment: @Spangle I have attached a screenshot. Please see question again

Comment: Can you also please go to the network tab in dev tools and show that error?

Comment: @Spangle it is showing `Cannot POST /api/metrics/`